# Sharepoint 2013 upload a solution

Tags: sharepoint-2013

When I go to site sittings and try to upload a new solution to Sharepoint 2013 there is no link "solutions" in the "Web Designer Galleries". In my local testing environment I was able to upload right there the newly created WebPart. What do I need to do to upload a solution (WebPart)?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNJ1U.png)

Answer (score 0):

MS has put a feature in o365 to disable custom scripting. Meaning that any parts or features related to custom code - in your case `Solutions` are no longer visible.

You can check your sharepoint settings with:

1. Inside o365 open the Admin Panel
2. In the left menu scroll down to Admin section and expand that section
3. Click SharePoint
4. Inside SharePoint Admin Center navigate to Settings
5. Search for `Custom Script` section

Now if you have those setup to `Prevent` you will not be able to see the solution gallery. You will have to determine if you want those to be turned on.

You can find more information here (for example how to set it up via PowerShell): http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=397546